# How to get filepath to send file to the server

Tags: android

I am not able send pdf and doc files to the server using okhttp because I am getting proper filepath. I have searched so many hints in stack overflow but not able to solve the problem. Please check my program where I did wrong and resolve the same. I have searched so many solution but not find proper solution so we request you to please check and make my program correct.

```
private void enable_docd() {

        Docd_btn.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                DocumentObject name= null;
                if(Spinner_Doc != null && Spinner_Doc.getSelectedItem() !=null ) 
                    name = (DocumentObject) Spinner_Doc.getSelectedItem();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();                     
                    intent.setType("*/*");                        
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose File to Upload.."),12);       
                } else  {
                    Toast.makeText (DocDialog.this,"Please Select Document",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();   

                }
            }
        });

    }

            if (requestCode == 12 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
                progress = new ProgressDialog (DocDialog.this);    
                progress.setTitle ("Uploading");
                progress.setMessage ("Please wait....");
                progress.show ( );   
                Thread t = new Thread (new Runnable ( ) {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {         
                        File h = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ().getPath (),"temp.pdf");   
                        String filepaths = h.getAbsolutePath ( );  
                        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient ( );   
                        String mimeTypesp = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName (h.getName ( ));
                        RequestBody filebodys = RequestBody.create (MediaType.parse (mimeTypesp), h);

                        DocumentObject documentObjects = (DocumentObject) Spinner_Doc.getSelectedItem ();

                        RequestBody requestBodysp = new MultipartBody.Builder ( )
                                .setType (MultipartBody.FORM)
                                .addFormDataPart ("id","")
                                .addFormDataPart ("extrainfoid",atr)
                                .addFormDataPart ("partyid",rtr)
                                .addFormDataPart ("documenttype", documentObjects.taskDocumentTypeId)
                                .addFormDataPart ("certificationfilepath","")
                                .addFormDataPart ("documentfilepath", filepaths.substring (filepaths.lastIndexOf ("/") + 1), filebodys)
                                .build ( );

                        okhttp3.Request requests = new okhttp3.Request.Builder ( )
                                .url (url1)
                                .post (requestBodysp)
                                .build ( );

                        try {
                            okhttp3.Response responsesp = client.newCall (requests).execute ( );
                            if (responsesp.isSuccessful ( )) {

                                ResponseBody responseBodys = responsesp.body ( );
                                // Here is your response you can get String response by calling string()
                                String resp = responseBodys.string ( );
                                Log.i ("Testing","Error: "+resp.toString ());
                                Intent intent = new Intent (DocDialog.this, AdditionalActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra ("obj",atr);
                                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                                finish();

                                progress.dismiss ( );
                            }


                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace ( );
                        }
                    }
                });

                t.start ( );

            }


        }
```

Comment: `am not able send pdf and doc files to the server using okhttp because I am getting proper filepath` ????